# CLASSPATH on Mac, and how does Mac look for mysql-connector-java-bin.jar

Tags: java, jdbc, classpath

Is there a default classpath on Mac OS X 10.6? When I `echo $CLASSPATH`, nothing would show up. In my `.profile`, I only see `PATH` variable being set. My problem is that My servlet cant seem to find a suitable driver to connect to the mysql server. I use `Eclipse`, with `Glassfish v3` and `MAMP` for MYSQL server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several methods of getting JARs to be seen by Java on Mac OS X:

- Place it in /Library/Java/Extensions
- Create/edit the CLASSPATH environment variable
- Specify the classpath explicitly with the -cp option.

The CLASSPATH environment variable is not set by default, however, you can set it if you so choose. Be aware, however, that any environment variables that you set in `~/.profile` will only take effect within your Terminal session and will not affect any GUI applications. If you want to set environment variables so that they affect your GUI applications, you can create a file named `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` that includes your environment variables. Any changes made to that file will take effect when you next login.

As has been observed, placing JARs in the extensions folder or modifying the CLASSPATH environment variable are generally bad ideas since they can lead to dependency hell. A better way is to bundle your JARs with your artifact and to set the metadata appropriately so that they are on your artifact's classpath. If you use [Apache Maven2](http://maven.apache.org/) to build your artifact, you can have it automatically download as well as bundle any thirdparty dependencies and set the classpath appropriately for your artifact.

Comment: the first 2 suggestions are BAD suggestions and the third one is not really an option when working with a Servlet container, you should include the .jar file in the lib directory of the .war you are deploying to your Servlet container.

Comment: you should NOT need to have a CLASSPATH it makes your machine really brittle and rife with .jar conflicts.

Comment: OK, when I develop on Netbean, I can see my War file, but not on eclipse. Does eclipse create war file for deployment? If so where do I put the jar file? inside WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: Aslo when setting the classpath i beleive you need to do so in the users environment.plist (/Users/username/.MacOSX/environment.plist) in addition to or instead of your .bash_profile. Could be worng about that but i seem having to do that with the svn-javahl and its dependencies.

Comment: Sigh...very where I go in the java world, I heard about maven. I looked at it before, quite robust and complex. Is it very important to know maven?

Comment: @Harry, Maven is definitely worth it, though I agree, it is a bit hard to configure.

Comment: just tell Eclipse to add the .jar file to the WEB-INF/lib dir, you do not need to deal with Maven if you are building with Eclipse

Comment: The simple way is Place it in /Library/Java/Extensions. Thanks for it!

Answer (score 5):

Do **not** use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. This is portability trouble. The whole environment variable is a mistake of the Sun guys. It's only useful for starters, but certainly not in real world. This would only confuse the starters more afterwards. Besides, appservers (and IDE's) completely ignores this environment variable. Do **not** put the libraries in the library of JRE or JDK. This is portability trouble as well. If you upgrade the JRE/JDK or run the application somewhere else, it won't work anymore.

In webapplications, you normally just drop webapp-specific 3rd party libraries in `Webapp/WEB-INF/lib`. This folder is covered by the webapp's default classpath. If those libraries are rather appserver-specific (e.g. JDBC driver is required to create a JNDI datasource which is managed by the appserver), then you need to drop them in `Appserver/lib`. This folder is covered by the appserver's default classpath. In case of Glassfish, you need to put it more specifically in the domain-specific `/lib` folder, e.g. `glassfish/domains/<domainname>/lib`.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled a lot with this one. Try adding the appserv-rt.jar (located on Glassfish lib directory) to your project's build path. (I't will drag all it's dependancies if you want to avoid this first create a library with the jar and then add the library to your build path.