# How do I setup and modify CLASSPATH on my mac (shell or eclipse)?

Tags: macos, classpath

How can I setup and modify CLASSPATH on my mac (shell or eclipse)?
    I wrote a class about certain kind of function to simplified "System.out.print()",and I want to import the class in other packages.
    To achieve the import, should I set up the CLASSPATH on my mac?
    (I use eclipse in mac OSX 10.6.6)

Answer (score 0):

You can update your ~/.profile to set your CLASSPATH. Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509138/classpath-on-mac-and-how-does-mac-look-for-mysql-connector-java-bin-jar) for more info...